# Pushing local docker image to openshift online

Tags: docker, openshift

I have a spring boot application running locally on docker on my machine.

The image name is `springio/spring-rest-hello-world` and the tag is `latest`. I want to push this to openshift online and get it running.

I think to do that the easiest way is to push the image up (correct me if I'm wrong).

Here is my attempt.

`oc login https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com:6443`

`oc project playpen`

`docker login -u myUser -p myToken default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com`

`docker tag springio/spring-rest-hello-world  default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com:5000/springio/spring-rest-hello-world`

`docker push default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com:5000/springio/spring-rest-hello-world`

With the error being...

`Get https://default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers`

I am a newb at this stuff so I am pretty sure I have something wrong. Appreciate it if someone could give me a hand with the steps required.

thanks

Comment: It looks like you tagged your image with `:5000`. Because you were able to login without specifying the port `:5000`, I would recommend leaving that off when tagging and pushing your image.

Comment: thanks. That got rid of the error above. i had a good read of the docker tag command as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment provided. No need to include the docker port when tagging the image.

I also needed to tag the image with the ocp project name included in the tag.

`docker tag springio/spring-rest-hello-world default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.us-east-1.starter.openshift-online.com/playpen/spring-rest-hello-world:latest`